# Clustering/Deduplicating data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a challenge where I need to reduce my indexed data, by clustering similar items into one. Actually, somewhat deduplicating data. For eg.

```
         Product Name                |    Category    |    Product Group           |   Attributes
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1- Board Marker - Blue           | Stationary     | White Board Markers     | Color = Blue, Type = Board
    2- Board Marker - Green          | Stationary    | White Board Markers   | Color = Green, Type = Board
```

In the new indexed data I need to store the data as:

```
Product Name                |    Category    |    Product Group           |  
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1-  Board Marker                | Stationary    | White Board Markers
```

TL,DR: Find items which are at least 90% similar, on properties such as Product Name, Category , Product Group, (some)Attributes, and generate a new index to store them. I am new to ElasticSearch and a noob at this.

PS. I asked a this question on the ElasticSearch forum but got no love.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/clustering-deduplicating-data-in-elasticsearch/96274